# Can you print letters accurately from html?

Tags: html, css

I want to create html documents that can then be printed and look (nearly) as good as Word documents, that is, they can serve as professional letters.

Can this be done, and if so, what's the best practices?

More background:

I'm making a web app where the user fills out html forms. The fields then populate fields in a pre-created document. This completed document should look or present professionally and be printable.

I've looked into doing this with pdfs but so far have had no luck, so I'm exploring this avenue.

Comment: Yes this can be done, you'll run into a lot of browser quirks, but print preview is accurate. There are a variety of print-specific styles that are reasonably well supported. You can also create an HTML document and "Print to PDF" to produce PDFs.